# Jordan decomposition of linear operators

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie subalgebra of the general Lie algebra $gl(V)$. For any $\phi\in gl(V)$, let $\phi_s$ and $\phi_n$ be the semisimple part and nilpotent part of $\phi$ respectively. 
Is $\phi_s, \phi_n\in \mathfrak{g}$ for any linear map $\phi\in \mathfrak{g}$?

PS. It is well-known that the answer is positive when $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no. Consider for example a $1$-dimensional subalgebra generated by $\phi \in \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ which is not semisimple or nilpotent.

Comment: A Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ with this property is called *decomposable*. Bourbaki's *Lie groups and Lie algebras* VII, §7 is devoted to these algebras. .

Comment: @abx: I have the original French edition of Bourbaki's Chapters 7-8, where $\S5$ of Chapter 7 seems to cover *scindable* (translated as splittable or decomposable Lie algbras)?

Comment: @Zhou:  While characteristic 0 is usually required here, algebraically closed usually isn't.

Comment: @Jim Humphreys: Oops, my mistake, it is indeed §5 and not 7. And *scindable* has been translated as decomposable, which might not be the best option.

Comment: @abx: In most of the literature, "scindable" is translated as "splittable", since "decomposable" already has a meaning in such contexts (e.g., "Levi decomposable") . I'm not sure what the English translator of Bourbaki's Chapter 7-8 does..

Comment: @Humphreys Thanks!